# How to change values in a list by using dict definitions python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list `l = [1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3]` and I want to use my dict `d = {1:'r', 2:'b', 3:'g'}` to get the result `l = [r, r, b, r, g, g, r, r, r, g]`? What is the most pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: Note that your expressions for list `l` will give syntax errors, at least in Python 2. You need commas between the items.

Comment: What have you tried? What were the results, and how did they compare to the expected results? This is a teaching and helping site, not a code-writing service. Please check the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for how to ask a good question for this site, and don't be afraid to ask for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Pythonic is probably a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
l = [d[x] for x in l]
```

For larger inputs, the following *might* be faster, but less Pythonic, as it pays a slightly higher setup cost but (on CPython reference interpreter) pushes the per-element work to the C layer, bypassing the (relatively slow) byte code interpreter:

```
l = list(map(d.__getitem__, l))  # `list()` wrapping should be omitted on Python 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The following list comprehension will do:

```
mapped = [d[item] for item in l]
```